# Why the data from excel cannot be inserted in r-markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I insert my data from the document file on desktop, it always shows error with this operation.

[image: The error is showed in this image]

Comment: Can you insert the code and error message directly into the question, rather than supplying a link. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Comment: You likely have the path to the file incorrect. You seem to be using a relative path but make sure that's relative to your current working directory (`getwd()`).

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using a Mac OS, and I think you'll have to try `read_excel("~/Desktop/...")`. Notice the `~` at the beginning.